# Create a *.txt File That is Named After the Input of a User

Tags: c

Example being like..

```
fPointer = fopen("%s.txt", "r");
```

I know this does not work however I was just curious if there was anything similar to this idea? I also would need to create the file too.

Comment: You could use sprintf to make the file name first, before opening it.

Answer (score 1):

You can juste use scanf to take user input and create filename with that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char filename[100] = "";
    
    printf("Enter file name : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", filename);
    strcat(filename, ".txt");
    
    FILE * userfile = fopen(filename, "w+");

    return 0;
}
```

Of course ideally you should check user input first to ensure there's no forbidden character in it.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! Been learning C in uni for the first time so this was very helpful c:

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void) {
  char word[100];
  char fileName[100];
  printf("Enter a word: ");
  scanf("%s", word);
  sprintf(fileName, "%s.txt", word);
  fopen(fileName, "w");
  return 0;
}
```

Try it online [here](https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/WhisperedImmenseLeadership#main.c).